# Docker \ commit a container with its data

Tags: docker, docker-registry

lots of documentation, but I still missing something. My Goal is to run one-time registry (2.0) push to it couple of images and export\commit the container.
I need to take it in zip file to machine without internet.

Thing is - the images I pushed to registry aren't kept. whenever I import the regsitry to test - it comes empty. I understand that commit\export will not work on mounted volumes - how do I "disable" the volumes of the initial registry docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather suggest you decouple the image (registry v2) from the data for transport by copying the needed images seperately and then mounting them into the registry container when running it.

Kind of like this:

On the machine you are preparing the registry, run a registry container using something like

```
docker run -d \
    --name registry \
    --restart=always \
    -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy \
    -e STORAGE_PATH=/srv/docker-registry \
    -v /srv/data/docker-registry:/srv/docker-registry \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5002:5000 \
    registry:2.0.0
```

Then tag your images to localhost:5000/repo-name/image-name and execute

```
docker push localhost:5000/repo-name/image-name
```

After that, tar/zip/whatever /srv/data/docker-registry and do

```
docker save -o ~/docker-registry-v2 registry:2.0.0
```

Copy the two archives to the target machine,

```
docker load -i  ~/docker-registry-v2
```

Untar/Unzip/Whatever the image archive and run the registry again wieht a similar run command as above, supplying the dir you unpacked the image archive to as the first path after -v.

With this technique, the repos and images in your registry will also survive container destroys and restarts.

Comment: amazing. will do that.